# how to automatically submit a spring security login form using JSP code?

Tags: facebook, jsp, spring-security, form-submit

I'm using spring security for normal login form, where users register and then enter their username and password to login. I'm using login with facebook and login with google options, I'm able to authenticate users and finally get user's info like email, first name, last name etc, After logging into either fb/google I'm using fb/google user email(unique) as user name and system generated password as login credentials so that these values will be entered automatically to spring security login form and then if I click on submit button he/she will be able to login and then session handling will be taken care by spring security as in case of normal user who registers in my website.

Since, all the steps described above are automated except last step i.e. submitting the form
I want to automate the last step also using either javascript or JSP. i tried submitting the form using javascript inside JSP but its unable to

```
    <%
    if(Success_login_with_facebook/Success_login_with_google)
    {
    email = fb_email/google_email;
    Sql query to get username and password from db using email;//unique row will be returned

    uname_db = username;
    uname_pass = password;


    out.println("<script>document.forms('login').submit();</script>");
    }

    %>

<div id="autologin" style="display:none">
    <form name="f" id='login' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" method="POST" >

        User ID  <input size=35 type='text' id="first" name='j_username' value='<%=uname_db %>'/>
        Password<input size=35 type='password' name='j_password' value='<%=pass_db %>'>

        <input type="hidden" name="_spring_security_remember_me" value=true>

        <input style="height:30px"  name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign In">

        </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should work, but it's missing one thing. You need to make sure that the form exists before trying to submit it wis JavaScript. In your example, you're doing an out.println above the form. Move this to below the form, and the JavaScript should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it did not work is because the html form has **submit button name as "submit",** and if we try to run the javascript **document.forms['login'].submit();** it will not submit the form. If the form submit button name is other than 'submit' then it will work.